# Terminate java thread in web application

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

My web application (on Tomcat) provides “on the fly” logic execution  functionality.
The problem is the “on the fly” logic  can contains infinite loop , or something long duration.

My solution is **timeout**: to run the “on the fly” logic in a new daemon thread and go back main thread in timeout, p-code as below:

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory(){
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        result.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }});

 Future<Object> future = executor.submit(callable/* 'on the fly' callable: it can be infinite loop, the callable is out of my control */);
 //Back to main thread
 return future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

However, the daemon thread is still running, although `future.get()` returns in timeout. The daemon is terminated until Tomcat stops.

Now my latest solution is create a **new Java process** `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java MyProgram")`. *MyProgram* contains `future.get()` shown before. The daemon is terminated once main thread quits as expected.

I am here to ask more elegant solution to terminate thread in web application. The new Java process is heavy and out control of web application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

threading in a managed environment is generally a bad idea. why not use some sort of abstraction like JMS to start a background handler every time someone sends a request ? that way you can control the number of active threads (jms pool size)

Comment: Yes. But Thread pool will be full if it doesn't have chance to terminate the running threads.

Comment: The Thread.stop() method is unsafe and thus deprecated. If the thread being stopped was modifying common data, that common data remains in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Vote up. It's inevitable to move the thread out of web container.